# Can i deploy local angularjs project to google application engine using ng deploy?

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, web-deployment, google-cloud-platform

I created a project local to my Mac using "ng cli"; specifically, "ng new."  The project runs locally, but I do not have a way to deploy it to my account in Google Cloud - Application Engine.

I followed Google's tutorial using gcloud commands in the cloud, but I prefer to use my local repository, etc. as I am running on "free" until I can afford to be commercially viable.

Comment: who is downgrading my question -- it is a legitimate question.  if you are downgrading, its probably because you know the answer, if so, share it.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** You require a billing account to create a REPO in GCP.

I finally found this in Google Cloud Platform documents.  So, basically, follow the instructions on Google's site (url below) to create a remote and local project.  Write your code in the local repo, then push to the remote repo and deploy with gcloud commands (in a cloud shell in https://console.cloud.google.com) from the remote repository.

https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/quickstart

*(Synopsis of the page intro ...)*

**Quickstart**

This page shows you how to set up a GCP repository and use it as a remote for a local Git repository.

The sections below walk you through the steps of creating a local Git repository that contains files for a sample App Engine application, adding a GCP repository as a remote, and pushing the contents of the local repository.